# How can I emulate more virtual CPU than physically available?

Tags: virtualization, emulation, smp

In VMWare you can use multiple CPU, but only as much as present on the host. Is there a way to use more CPU than physically available ?

It would be to :

- test software designed to run on an expensive 16-way box on commodity 2-way boxes.
- Use an image designed for 2-way on a 1-way host
- test software on *not-power-of-2*-way (think 3) (*Although this could eventually be done on a 4-way box*)

In VMWare you can use multiple CPU, but only as much as present on the host. Is there a way to use more CPU than physically available ?

It would be to :

- test software designed to run on an expensive 16-way box on commodity 2-way boxes.
- Use an image designed for 2-way on a 1-way host
- test software on *not-power-of-2*-way (think 3) (*Although this could eventually be done on a 4-way box*)

**Update:**

I specifically want be able to run a 16-way configured OS on a 2-way hardware, not basic over-subscribing (like 16 2-way on a 4-way hardware) that is effectively handled by almost every virtualization software currently available.

I also don't really want to invest in a very specific solution if I don't have to since the idea is to limit the investements required.

And I cannot just increase the number of the threads as it has been cleverly suggested since :

- In one application, I would like to be able to test the self-regulation of process numbers.
- I want also to be able to see the impact of having a few number of big SMP (16+ way) hosts over a big number of small hosts (1 or 2 way).

**Update(bis):**

I finally found out that [QEMU](http://www.nongnu.org/qemu/) does exactly this.

Comment: Can you refine your question?  Do you want to run one Windows (or Unix or whatever) 16-way instance on a 2-way box under virtualization?  The way your question is written, it might be interpreted as running 8 2-way instances on a 2-way box, which is what Chopper3 was thinking.  Just trying to make it more clear so others don't make the same mistake.

Comment: You got it right : one 16-way on one 2-way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [QEMU](http://www.nongnu.org/qemu/) offers the `-smp X` launch option that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you do find an emulator that will do this, the reality is that you won't be able to fully test in this scenario - race conditions, locks, and such can't be fully tested to work in a parallel environment if you are still running everything essentially sequentially.

-Adam

Answer (score 3):

VMWare DOES let you oversubscribe CPUs though, i.e. if you have dual quad-core Xeons (i.e. 8 cores total) you can have 6 x dual vCPU VMs. Obviously if all 6 VMs 'go white' at 100% CPU you're going to run into performance issues but that is, hopefully, unlikely to happen. Same goes for memory too by the way. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: No, he specifically asked to run a 16-way machine on a 2-way box, not run 8 2-way machines on a 2-way box.

Comment: Brent, I answered his question before he updated with that information - downvoting was a bit harsh!

Comment: In the spirit of - uhhh, Christmas? - I upvoted it. ;-)

Comment: it's always the problem when you answer quickly - you can be proved wrong with further edits :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you need some serious simulation to do that, like [Simics](http://www.virtutech.com/solutions/technology/multicore) or similar.

When it comes to simple testing just using more threads than there are cores would provide at least some useful data, right?

It sounds like it would be ludicrously cpu-demanding to emulate more cores - at least in any meaningful way. But I could be wrong ^^

Comment: Simics gets the idea, hence +1, but is quite... overkill ? :-) I thought about a more "mainstream" solution... I edited the question to reflect your remarks

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth over-doing ^^

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't run a 16-way image on a 2-way box.  If you don't mind spending a little money, get a few used IBM 440's off Ebay.  You can daisy-chain them together to build one 16-way box, and they're absurdly cheap, like sub-$200.  They weigh a ton, and they're loud, and they use a lot of power, and they're not particularly fast (all single-core) but they will achieve what you're after.  Plus they run VMware ESX - I've used them since v2.5.

The daisy-chaining cable isn't usually included, so you'll need to find a source for those.  And you have to make sure that all of the 440's have the same CPU speed.

If you're in the South Florida area, let me know and I can hook you up with a shop that might sell theirs.